# Configuring eevee glass reflections

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass, reflection

Blender version: 2.82rc, 2.83alpha.

I am trying to set up eevee to properly show reflections on my glass material.

The glass object is an uv sphere, which I cut in half and then applied solidify modifier, so that it became a hollow semisphere.

When i render in cycles i can see the proper reflection of the purple monkey head:

[image: cycles-correct-reflection]

But when i render using eevee, there is no reflection of the monkey or the floor plane:

[image: eevee-lacks-reflections]

In eevee i have tried to add spherical reflection cubemap around my glass object, but it did not help:

[image: reflection cubemap settings]

The eevee screen space reflections settings i tried:

[image: screen space reflections settings]

And indirect lighting settings:

[image: indirect ligting settings]

My glass material uses simple transmissive principal bsdf shader:

[image: glass material nodes]

Is there any way to make eevee reflections closer to the cycles result? Is it possible to see the other objects properly reflected? The blend file i used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rljUoxhp4Ajbm7JIjpGwjlmQCButQ3BR/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked that the clip distance is correct in the reflection cubemap? "*Clipping Start*" should be slightly larger than the size of your object (the glass sphere) and Suzanne must be between *clipping start* and *clipping end*.
I suggest to activate "*Clipping*" in "*Viewport Display*" in Reflection Cubemap settings as in next image:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That resolved the issue with missing reflection. But now i see a weird extra reflection of the floor with a hole in it: https://i.imgur.com/jDByQGD.png Does it look like eevee limitation or could it be prevented with some setting?

Comment: yes it is weird, but there is not enough information to understand what originates the problem, I don't think it is due to an Eevee limitation.