# Can't get a transparent background for glass

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, glass

[image]

I need to make the bottle glass transparent in eevee. I used Principled shader with transmission value set to 1 for glass effect.

Comment: Have you activated "Screen Space Reflection" and "Refraction" in Eevee render settings, and "Screen Space Reflection" in the material settings of the glass? Have a look here for screenshots:
[Configuring eevee glass reflections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/165029/107598)

Comment: hello @umer Asghar , can you tell how did you acheive this glass effect what materiasl you used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set *Blend Mode* in material to *Alpha Blend* and *Shadow Mode* to *Alpha Hashed*.

[image]

or try this:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't change anything for me. Should this make the background (that is supposed to be alpha) visible through the object? Can you make a screenshot?

Comment: yes i can - i updated the answer....but didn't ask!? ;)

Comment: I Don't think he's seen it yet, but I was curious myself. This shows the BG HDRi, but not transparent BG.

Comment: thats why i added the green block partially behind it so you can see it is transparent...

Comment: But the background isn't check the original screenshot it should show the alpha checkers.

Comment: the Bg hdri works fine for me the trnasparent BG is not showing

Comment: can you show us your blend file, so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

Mixing it with transparent shader worked !. I was looking way much hard on it the answer was simple
Thanks @Chris
[image]

Comment: but the image texture on glass becomes a bit dull....but i will play around to see what i can get